# How to login to route53 using an access key ID and secret

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am supposed do some configuration inside Amazon Route 53.

My client has provided me a User Name, Access Key Id and Secret Access Key.

What url do I navigate to, to login using the provided credentials.

?

Answer (score 0):

You can't log in to the web console located at https://signin.aws.amazon.com, where one would normally go, with those credentials. You'd need a username and password for root access, and a  username, password and account number if you were a IAM user.

It might be worth it to ask your client to create an [IAM](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/) user for you.

But with those credentials, you can gain access to everything using a variety of first and third-party tools, provided those are credentials from the root account. You could use the command line, powershell, or even HTTP requests to complete your task.

But there is no simple URL that you can use to log in with this amount of information.

Try one of these though:

https://aws.amazon.com/developertools/Amazon-Route-53